# Is One Key Recovery on the Bios of the laptop? (transferring harddrives)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, windows-8.1, backup

Lenovo 510p ideapad

I need to changeout a 1tb hdd for 2tb drive. I'm used to making a windows backup of my harddrive on an external drive, then inserting the windows disks when the new drive is inserted and loaded....installing windows....then installing the backup.

I don't have repair disks though, everything is on partitions of my C drive. Also my backup was made using OKR (one key recovery), so I need that software on the new drive.

When I insert the new hdd and boot it up, will I have the boot option to recover via one key recovery?

If not, what process should I pursue instead? I can make different backups as the hdd is still in my laptop atm, but I eventually need to load the backup that was made using OKR.

My partitions look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU0r1.jpg)

Comment: One Key Recovery is simply third-party Lenovo software that is installed.  However, the Lenovo button is indeed, unique to Lenovo hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I think the recovery mechanism of OKR determines how it can restore the partition. If it is possible to make the two hard disk drives connected at the same time (maybe one on the machine and another connected via USB, if there is only one HDD slot in the laptop), you should be able to boot from the 1 TB HDD, and then possible to boot to OKR and recover it to the other HDD (2 TB).

Comment: Can someone expand on the validity of this.